# How to cycle through multiple URL via redirection?

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser

I remember encountering a site that redirected to multiple pages. For instance it would redirect to site 1 for 5 seconds, in 5 more seconds it redirected to another page and so on. I made sure it wasn't an extension thing and those pages were not related to each other in anyway. Is there anyway to achieve this client-side via javascript?

Comment: Only by placing code in each individual page. Can be a `<meta>` tag or javascript redirect. Alternative is a single page app that does all this internally

Answer (score 0):

You can put a script on each individual page that redirects to the following page.

If you don't have control of the pages in your chain of redirection, then you can simply show the pages in an `<iframe>`, which will rotate between the pages.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of the iframe, however, the url was changing in the address bar.

Comment: @Babiker Can change url in address bar also when change iframe source